# how to force scikit-learn DictVectorizer not to discard features?

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

Im trying to use scikit-learn for a classification task.
My code extracts features from the data, and stores them in a dictionary like so:

```
feature_dict['feature_name_1'] = feature_1
feature_dict['feature_name_2'] = feature_2
```

when I split the data in order to test it using `sklearn.cross_validation` everything works as it should. The problem Im having is when the test data is a new set, not part of the learning set (although it has the same exact features for each sample). after I fit the classifier on the learning set, when I try to call `clf.predict` I get this error:

```
ValueError: X has different number of features than during model fitting.
```

I am assuming this has to do with this (out of the DictVectorizer docs):

> Named features not encountered during fit or fit_transform will be
>   silently ignored.

`DictVectorizer` has removed some of the features I guess... How do I disable/work around this feature?

Thanks

=== EDIT ===

The problem was as larsMans suggested that I was fitting the DictVectorizer twice.

Comment: The ignoring of unseen features is supposed to *prevent* having different shapes at training and test time. Please show a [minimal example](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the error. You're probably fitting the `DictVectorizer` twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `fit_transform` on the training set, and only `transform` on the test set.

Comment: thanks, you saved my day. This totally solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure to call the previously built scaler and selector transforms on the test data?

```
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(trainingData)
selector = SelectPercentile(f_classif, percentile=90)
selector.fit(scaler.transform(trainingData), labelsTrain)
...
...
predicted = clf.predict(selector.transform(scaler.transform(testingData)))#
```