# Handling categorical features using scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

**What am I doing?**

I am solving a classification problem using Random Forests. I have a set of strings of a fixed length (10 characters long) that represent DNA sequences. DNA alphabet consists of 4 letters, namely `A`, `C`, `G`, `T`.

Here's a sample of my raw data:

```
ATGCTACTGA
ACGTACTGAT
AGCTATTGTA
CGTGACTAGT
TGACTATGAT
```

Each DNA sequence comes with experimental data describing a real biological response; the molecule was seen to elicit biological response (1), or not (0).

**Problem:**

The training set consists of both, categorical (nominal) and numerical features. It is of the following structure:

```
training_set = [
  {'p1':'A', 'p2':'T', 'p3':'G', 'p4':'C', 'p5':'T', 
   'p6':'A', 'p7':'C', 'p8':'T', 'p9':'G', 'p10':'A', 
   'mass':370.2, 'temp':70.0},
  {'p1':'A', 'p2':'C', 'p3':'G', 'p4':'T', 'p5':'A', 
   'p6':'C', 'p7':'T', 'p8':'G', 'p9':'A', 'p10':'T', 
   'mass':400.3, 'temp':67.2},
]

target = [1, 0]
```

I successfully create the classifier using the [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#loading-features-from-dicts) class to encode nominal features, but I'm having problems while performing predictions on my testing data.

Below is the simplified version of my code accomplished so far:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

training_set = [
  {'p1':'A', 'p2':'T', 'p3':'G', 'p4':'C', 'p5':'T', 
   'p6':'A', 'p7':'C', 'p8':'T', 'p9':'G', 'p10':'A', 
   'mass':370.2, 'temp':70.0},
  {'p1':'A', 'p2':'C', 'p3':'G', 'p4':'T', 'p5':'A', 
   'p6':'C', 'p7':'T', 'p8':'G', 'p9':'A', 'p10':'T', 
   'mass':400.3, 'temp':67.2},
]

target = [1, 0]

vec = DictVectorizer()
train = vec.fit_transform(training_set).toarray()

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000)
clf = clf.fit(train, target)


# The following part fails.
test_set =   {
  'p1':'A', 'p2':'T', 'p3':'G', 'p4':'C', 'p5':'T', 
  'p6':'A', 'p7':'C', 'p8':'T', 'p9':'G', 'p10':'A', 
  'mass':370.2, 'temp':70.0}
vec = DictVectorizer()
test = vec.fit_transform(test_set).toarray()
print clf.predict_proba(test)
```

As a result, I got an error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must  match the input. 
Model n_features is 20 and  input n_features is 12
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to force scikit-learn DictVectorizer not to discard features?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770147/how-to-force-scikit-learn-dictvectorizer-not-to-discard-features)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the same `DictVectorizer` object which created the train dataset to `transform` the `test_set`:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

training_set = [
  {'p1':'A', 'p2':'T', 'p3':'G', 'p4':'C', 'p5':'T', 
   'p6':'A', 'p7':'C', 'p8':'T', 'p9':'G', 'p10':'A', 
   'mass':370.2, 'temp':70.0},
  {'p1':'A', 'p2':'C', 'p3':'G', 'p4':'T', 'p5':'A', 
   'p6':'C', 'p7':'T', 'p8':'G', 'p9':'A', 'p10':'T', 
   'mass':400.3, 'temp':67.2},
]

target = [1, 0]

vec = DictVectorizer()
train = vec.fit_transform(training_set).toarray()

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000)
clf = clf.fit(train, target)


# The following part fails.
test_set =   {
  'p1':'A', 'p2':'T', 'p3':'G', 'p4':'C', 'p5':'T', 
  'p6':'A', 'p7':'C', 'p8':'T', 'p9':'G', 'p10':'A', 
  'mass':370.2, 'temp':70.0}

test = vec.transform(test_set).toarray()
print clf.predict_proba(test)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great. However, I noticed that dealing with a large number of strings, makes the resulting matrix very wide and overloads my memory. I was wondering, if you could suggest me some other ways for creating classifiers. In Scikit-learn documentation I read about [feature hashing](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) but I can't find a way to use it on my data.

Comment: @s_sherly To make `FeatureHasher` work, you need to replace the categorical features with dummy variables yourself: `"p1=A": 1` etc. But it might be a better idea to do feature selection and/or dimension reduction with `TruncatedSVD` on the sparse matrix that comes out of the vectorizer.